# Matlab - Trouble using multiple timers

Tags: matlab, timer

Hi I am writing a program on matlab which uses multiple timers. Each timer calls a different function.

I have

```
t = timer('Period', 0.1,...
                     'StartDelay',1,...
        'ExecutionMode', 'fixedRate',...
        'TimerFcn',@moverobots)...

t1 = timer('Period', 0.1,...
        'StartDelay',1,...
        'ExecutionMode', 'fixedRate',...
        'TimerFcn',@moveintruder)...

t2 = timer('Period', 0.1,...
        'StartDelay',1,...
        'ExecutionMode', 'fixedRate',...
        'TimerFcn',@moveintruderout)...

start(t);

start(t1);

start(t2);
```

My problem is that when I run my program `start(t)` is underlined and I get following error:

> "Parse error at start: usage might be invalid MATLAB syntax"

t has well is underlined and message says

> "value assigned to variable 't' might be unused"

I have noticed that if I get rid of `t2` and `start(t2)` I do not get this error and the program works. Whats wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at the end if each timer you have 3 dots which is the continuation characters. so essentially combining all the functions to one giant mess.  t=()
not
t=()...